# SQL Update value by other values of the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where I have FKs to other tables and timestamps for each record in this table. For example:

```
ID    FK    Timestamp
1     1     2015-05-05
2     1     2015-05-06
3     1     2015-05-07
4     2     2015-04-08
5     2     2015-04-09
6     2     2020-04-10 <- this timestamp should be set to timestamp of 5. row
7     2     2015-04-12
8     3     2015-05-06
```

The problem is that some of the timestamps I got contains values from the future which should be set back to a normal timestamp. For example the one before this step, on the same FK.

I have a query that selects all records from the future, and gets their max timestamps as well (before the future one):

```
select ws1.Id, ws1.Timestamp, ws1.workitem_id,
    (select max(Timestamp) from WorkSteps where WorkSteps.WorkItem_Id = ws1.WorkItem_Id AND Timestamp<GETDATE() AND worksteps.Id<ws1.id)
from worksteps ws1 
where ws1.Timestamp > GETDATE()
order by WorkItem_Id;
```

How can I transform this into an update?

**Update**

Ok, I think I got it:

```
update worksteps set Timestamp = 
    (select max(Timestamp) from WorkSteps ws1 where ws1.WorkItem_Id = worksteps.WorkItem_Id AND Timestamp<GETDATE() AND ws1.Id<worksteps.id)
where worksteps.Timestamp > GETDATE();
```

Comment: You should remove the question if you have a viable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your query into a derived table or CTE and join to it in an UPDATE:

```
UPDATE t
SET TimeStamp=q.{The Alias you need to provide for your sub-select}
FROM worksteps t
INNER JOIN (Your Query) q
  ON t.{ThePrimaryKey}=q.{ThePrimaryKey}
```

This is psuedocode, obviously:  you need to replace the parts in curly-braces with the actual values they describe.